# Getting error "Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/categorymenu.phtml" in Magento system log

Tags: magento, error-logging, php, magento-1.8

I have been having a few problems with a Magento development site I am making and so I thought I should go through all the logs and fix all the errors to see if this solves most things. However, I have come across one error that I don't quite understand.

```
2014-02-10T09:20:27+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/categorymenu.phtml
```

I have just re-downloaded a copy of Magento 1.8.1. and I can't see this file in there anywhere so I don't understand what should be in it, what it is doing or why it is needed?

Has anybody see this error before or knows what could fix it?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: Forgot link to site http://bit.ly/1fXWgHq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a custom menu module installed as this file is not a default magento template file from memory?

I suspect you have a third party module installed acting as a menu system and as the error suggests the template file `categorymenu.phtml` does not exist in the location `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/`.

You do not add template files to base as this is magento's default template location, you should setup a theme or simply add it to the default theme (not base) so it gets included. If this is a third party module I would re-install it, or find the missing template file and put it in the correct location, or contact the module provider for assistance.

I would also advise you read up on how Magento handles theme's: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes

Comment: Clearly this is a template issue with a non standard magento template file as my answer suggests.

Comment: Downvote wasn't me but thanks for the reply, I did infact install a menu system of sorts that moves categories to a dropdown on search pages etc, as the list was to long. I think it could be that so I shall look through now and remember the name so that I can reinstall/replace it to see if that does the job.